# google SMTP email sending not working python

Tags: python, django, smtp

I am trying to learn how to send emails using google smtp. I am just trying to verify that I am able to send emails. They way I want it to work is when a user registers to my site it will automatically send an email to them saying "thanks for registering..."

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com.'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pw'
```

views.py (only showing register)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import logout, authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage, send_mail
from django.conf import settings

def register(request):
    """" Register a new user. """
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Display blank registration form
        form = RegisterForm()
    else:
        # Process completed form.
        form = RegisterForm(data=request.POST)

        new_user = form.save()
        # Log the user in then redirect to home page.
        authenticated_user = authenticate(
            username=new_user.username, password=request.POST['password1'])
        login(request, authenticated_user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogging_logs:index'))

        subject = "Thank you for registering to blogging site."
        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        to_email = ['sending_to@gmail.com']
        body = "Thanks for registering to the website let me know what you think"
        send_mail(subject=subject, from_email=from_email,
                  recipient_list=to_email, message=body, fail_silently=False)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', context)
```

I have no errors when creating a new user. but I am not receiving the email I am trying to send in my views.py

Comment: because you are only defining the function without actually calling it

Comment: Could be because you're redirecting before calling `send_mail`

Comment: @SachinKukreja that did it thank you! even though I am redirecting before I call it should still send them email though?

Comment: No. `return` call will exit the function and the code after it wont run.